# Make VLC default to open video DVD?

Tags: vlc, dvd

When inserting a video DVD, I used to be able to click on the DVD an have it open in VLC.  When I installed Handbrake, it took ownership of opening video DVDs.  I know how to assign "open with" to a particular file type, but that option isn't available for a disk.  How do I set VLC as the default program to open video DVDs?

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.  VLC (snap version) 3.0.4 Vetinan

VLC can play the DVD with no problem if I directly tell it to open it from within VLC.

The "default applications" for music and video are already set to VLC.  Many video file type are set to open with VLC including the VOB files found on video DVDs.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something complicated but the answer was so simple that I missed it.

- Go to Setting.
- Select "Devices"
- Select "Removable media"
- On the line that says "DVD video" select VLC from the pull down.

(Note that Handbrake wasn't selected but somehow it was the default.)

Edit: if you don't want the DVD to auto open, just set "DVD video" back to "Do nothing and VLC will stick as the default to open dvds.